# Excel VBA - Pull data from external books and paste into the next blank row in multiple tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on automating a workbook in Excel, and I'm running into a few issues with my VBA code. I'd paste it here, but I've been through so many iterations, it's pretty unusable.

The goal is to have the active book 'grab' the data out of several workbooks containing raw data when it is opened, and put the copied data into a few tabs that can be used to populate various charts on a dashboard tab. Each workbook containing raw data should go into its own separate tab within the active workbook. Broken into steps, I am thinking I need the below process to occur:

- Open Active Book
- Open hidden tab 'Sheet1'
- Open raw data book 1(e.g. c:\Raw Data.xls)
- Copy data from specified location (e.g. [Raw Data.xls]Sheet1!$A$3:$AE$64) in the raw data book 1
- Paste copied data into Active Book, into specific worksheet, into first empty row (e.g. [Active Book.xls]Sheet1!**first empty row**)
- Hide tab 'Sheet1' in Active Book
- Close raw data book 1
- Repeat process using raw data book 2 and sheet2 of Active Book
- Repeat process using raw data book 3 and sheet3 of Active Book
- Only after data is populated into the destination tabs (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 in the Active Book), can the user interact (click into cells, change tabs, etc) with the workbook

I know this is simple - I'm getting frustrated, as I'm a newbie and the syntax (and multiple variations of syntax) is really throwing me for a loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Where are you getting stuck? Briefly:

> Open Active Book

If its active, it's already open? Reference with object 'ThisWorkbook'

> Open hidden tab 'Sheet1'

You don't need to unhide sheets to "VBA" them... If you're going to be creating new sheets for each datafile I'd recommend creating new via:

```
Set wsDestination = thisworkbook.sheets.add
wsDestination.visible = xlSheetHidden ' Might as well hide it now
```

If you're wanting to match specific raw data files with specific worksheets, maybe use a "select"

> Open raw data book 1(e.g. c:\Raw Data.xls)

```
Set wbSource = Application.Workbooks.Open("c:\Raw Data.xls")
Set wsSource = wbSource.sheets(1)

'If need Select (see above):
Select case wbSource.name
    Case "Raw Data A.xls" ' If line above changes to .Open(Workbooks[i]) or something
        set wsDestination = sheet1
    Case "Raw Data B.xls"
        set wsDestination = sheet2
    '...
End Select
```

> Copy data from specified location (e.g. [Raw
>   Data.xls]Sheet1!$A$3:$AE$64) in the raw data book 1 Paste copied data
>   into Active Book, into specific worksheet, into first empty row (e.g.
>   [Active Book.xls]Sheet1!first empty row)

```
intBlankRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Counta(wsDestination.columns(1)) + 1 ' Note this only works if there are no blanks in column 1 otherwise you'll need another method: there are some good tricks if you google "find last cell vba"
wsSource.cells.copy wsDestination.cells(intBlankRow,1) ' No need to copy and paste in seperate lines: you can just pass destination to the copy function
```

> Hide tab 'Sheet1' in Active Book

You don't need to

> Close raw data book 1

wbSource.close

> Repeat process using raw data book 2 and sheet2 of Active Book Repeat
>   process using raw data book 3 and sheet3 of Active Book Only after
>   data is populated into the destination tabs (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 in
>   the Active Book), can the user interact (click into cells, change
>   tabs, etc) with the workbook

Wrap the whole thing in a big loop... If you wanna do it the easy way, create an array with your workbook names and iterate through it. Otherwise present the user with a FileDialogue so they can select the workbooks they want to import... this ofcourse depends on what I was saying above: do you want to create new worksheets each time or import specific raw data in to specific sheets...